# custom mesh object orientation is not correct using

Tags: unity, c#, mesh

I am making a custom mesh with the help of [**Traingulator**](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=Triangulator) script.  At runtime, user can click and and generate a point then mesh creation start. Here is the way i am getting user input.

```
void Update()
    {
        RaycastHit hit;
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
        {
            if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
            {
                GameObject sphere = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Sphere);
                sphere.transform.position = hit.point;
                sphere.transform.localScale = new Vector3(0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f);
                positions.Add(sphere.transform.position);
                positionsVector2.Add(new Vector2(sphere.transform.position.x, sphere.transform.position.z));

                traingulatorTester.MeshMaker(positionsVector2.ToArray());
            }
        }

    }
```

And here is the mesh maker function that calling tringulator

```
 public void MeshMaker(Vector2[] vertices2D)
    {
        // Use the triangulator to get indices for creating triangles
        Triangulator tr = new Triangulator(vertices2D);
        int[] indices = tr.Triangulate();

        // Create the Vector3 vertices
        Vector3[] vertices = new Vector3[vertices2D.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < vertices.Length; i++)
        {
            vertices[i] = new Vector3(vertices2D[i].x, vertices2D[i].y, 0);
        }

        // Create the mesh
        Mesh msh = new Mesh();
        msh.vertices = vertices;
        msh.triangles = indices;
        msh.RecalculateNormals();
        msh.RecalculateBounds();
        if (gameObject.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>() == null)
        {
            // Set up game object with mesh;
            gameObject.AddComponent(typeof(MeshRenderer));
            filter = gameObject.AddComponent(typeof(MeshFilter)) as MeshFilter;
        }
        filter.mesh = msh;

    }
```

Now the problem is the rotation of the custom mesh object is not correct look at this.
[image]

Now I have manually set the rotation.
[image]

Comment: Try ```vertices[i] = new Vector3(vertices2D[i].y, vertices2D[i].x, 0);``` or ```vertices[i] = new Vector3(vertices2D[i].x, 0, vertices2D[i].y);```

Comment: It slightly improved the orientation but still in the air and not well placed.

Answer (score 1):

Triangles, normals and other things seem fine in the images, so it must be a problem with vertices. you placed Z axis of spheres in Y axis of positionsVector2 so you have to put Y axis of positionsVector2 into Z axis of new vectors.

```
vertices[i] = new Vector3(vertices2D[i].x, 0, vertices2D[i].y);
```

Comment: Thanks it is very helpful but after adding multiple points the whole mesh become invisible as appear showing form bottom.

Comment: @MuhammadFaizanKhan maybe not enough vertices for triangle generation?

Comment: Vertex count should be Multiples of 3. You can add more vertices if you don't have enough vertices in ```MeshMaker``` method.

Comment: but the mesh normal are rotated to 180.

Comment: when i add more points the normal get inverted.

Comment: You can check the problem here. https://youtu.be/5YJSOD6wuhU

Comment: @MuhammadFaizanKhan Normals are calculated from the triangle vertex order. Do your mesh normals flip again back to normal when adding more and more points? if yes, find the pattern, if not then you can flip the normals by code in each generation.

Comment: A short cut adopted, the double sided shader has used.

Comment: Keep in mind using the Double-sided shader increases calculations and causes less performance. So only use it for meshes that are visible from both sides.

Comment: Yeah you are right, but i didn't find any solution.